# How to read the WiFi RSSI (signal strength) on iOS using Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, wifi, rssi

I need to read every 5 seconds the WiFi signal strength on an iPod, (the app is private, no store). What can I do in order to achieve such task? I am not finding any documentation about that. Is it even possible?

Comment: To get that information, your app needs a special entitlement from Apple. Start your research here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension